find a column where specific rows contain specific values
I'm trying to create a function that will allow me to find a column where specific rows contain specific values, and return the value of row 1 for all columns that contain those specific values
I'm not sure what to try, this is a sample data:




Job 1
Job 2
Job 3
Job 4
Job 5
Job 6




Type
Small
Medium
Medium
Large
Small
Large


Colour
Red
Blue
Green
Green
Red
Yellow


Style
Round
Square
Scallop
Square
Round
Square


Flavour
Apple
Banana
Orange
Banana
Apple
Apple



I'm needing to find as an example, results that match a set of the first column variables (Type, Colour, Style, Flavour) and for each column that contains the values, return the job number (row 1 value), for example if I wanted to find Type: Small and Flavour: Apple, the formula should return Job 1 & Job 5
It might not always be Type and Flavour, it could be 2 or more variables to match and return the job number for the matching results

It might not always be Type and Flavour, it could be 2 or more variables can you show how you will input multiple variable? Without seeing this, we can't suggest formula.

link
For the variables I would specify which variable and what I would want to search for in a smaller table underneath the data, above is a link to a spreadsheet with the example, I just have no idea how to combine the functions to get the 2+ variables to be matched and return the Job #

Thank you for sharing a sample spreadsheet. The question has currently been answered three times. If those answers don't work for you, please comment those answers and point out why they don't work for you.


find Type: Small and Flavour: Apple, the formula should return Job 1 & Job 5

Use filter(), like this:
=filter(B1:Z1, "Small" = B2:Z2, "Apple" = B5:Z5)

To match by different rows, it would be easiest to put each selection criteria in a dropdown cell of its own, and use additional instances of filter() to choose the row within the formula above, like this:
=filter( 
  B1:Z1, 
  B10 = filter(B2:Z5, B9 = A2:A5), 
  C10 = filter(B2:Z5, C9 = A2:A5)
)

The formula expects to find criteria in cells B9:C10. To add more conditions, continue adding lines like D10 = filter(B2:Z5, D9 = A2:A5).
To ignore criteria that has been left blank, use this pattern:
=filter( 
  B1:Z1, 
  (B10 = "") + (B10 = filter(B2:Z5, B9 = A2:A5)), 
  (C10 = "") + (C10 = filter(B2:Z5, C9 = A2:A5)), 
  (D10 = "") + (D10 = filter(B2:Z5, D9 = A2:A5)) 
)


See filter().

thank you that is amazing! it works great and seems scalable if I was to add more data for each job. If i wanted to add a 3rd parameter, would I just copy/adjust to add a 3rd condition?

It works to add the 3rd condition too, thank you so much

You can try something like this:
=FILTER(B1:1,REGEXMATCH(QUERY(B2:5,,9^9),JOIN(" ",IF(B7:B10="",".*?",B7:B10))))



Is it possible to have the variable type (eg. Type, Colour etc) so if I said search for Type=small, it would only search in Row 2 for Small, in some cases the small answer may be in another row as well as I only put a small selection of data

Use QUERY's where clause with TRANSPOSEd data:
=LET(
  rg, A1:G5, 
  typeRow, 2, 
  flavourRow, 5, 
  typeFilter, "Small", 
  flavourFilter, "Apple" ,
   QUERY(
    TRANSPOSE(rg),
    "Select Col1 
      where Col"&typeRow&"='"&typeFilter&"' 
      and Col"&flavourRow&"='"&flavourFilter&"' "
  )
)


thank you for your idea, it is not dynamic enough for my use case as my variables will vary in a larger set of data

@Liz You can always add more filters as shown above.
